# Chrome Content Scripts not loading JS

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to work on a Chrome browser extension which does fun things on a contextmenu.  The problem is, I can't get the JS files to load within the manifest.json content_scripts.

I don't receive an error, the files simply do not load.

The scripts are good, if I put them in my background page, they fire fine through that background page.  The downside of that is it's restricted to only the background page.

```
{
"name": "Mini",
"description": "Mini",      
"permissions": ["contextMenus","management","contentSettings","tabs","http://*/*","https://*/*","editable"],
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 1,
"background_page": "mini.html",
"icons" : {"16" : "mini.png"},
"contexts" : ["link","tab","page"],
"content_scripts": [{"matches":["<all_urls>"],"js":["jquery172min.js","mini.js"]}]
}
```

I've tried all forms of matches, including `"http://\*/\*", "https://\*/\*", "\*://\*/\*"`

I've tried whitespaces, no whitespaces.  I'm drawing a blank here.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

alert("page is ready");
},true);
```

My apologies for that.  This is a copy of the javascript/Jquery I'm using to test whether the extension has loaded or not.  It's just a simple alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) cannot use the [`chrome.contextMenus`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html) API (in fact, these can only use [some of the `chrome.extension` methods](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#content%20scripts)).

It's possible to apply [match patterns](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) to individual menu items, via [`chrome.contextMenus.create({title: 'Test', documentUrlPatterns: 'http://*/*'});`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create).
Created menu items can also be modified ([`chrome.contextMenus.update`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-update)) and removed ([`chrome.contextMenus.remove`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-remove)).

To communicate between a Content script and the background page, see [Message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).

Comment: Thanks!

The problem right now is I can't even get to test that part out.  Even should I put a simple alert which triggers on page load (via jquery) it doesn't trigger.  When I look in the developer panel, no scripts are loaded for that extension.

Comment: Which dev tools? Content scripts are invisible, and can only be accessed **indirectly** from the background page's dev tools. Content script's `console.log` messages show up in the page on which it is active though.

Comment: Ok, I was talking about the developer tools that come with Chrome.  So, I wouldn't see it as loaded.  However, should I not see the alert trigger?  I'll look into console.log.  I didn't know about that one.  Thanks

Comment: @MichaelLockwood I'm not a mind reader. Which `alert` are you talking about? Please include relevant details in your question (Use the `edit` link to edit the answer).

Comment: My apologies Rob.  I'm trying to provide as much info as I can.  However, I'm confused on this.  Adding the files to the content_scripts in the Manifest.json should load those scripts in a scope which includes all tabs.  Is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelLockwood Content scripts will only automatically execute if: 1. The page on which it's activated is matched 2. If you're in incognito mode, the tick at "Run extension in incognitio mode" is ticked. 3. If you're visiting a `file://` protocol, the tick at `Allow access to local-URLs` is ticked. (The checkbox for 2 and 3 are available at `chrome://extensions/`, Developer mode). Also, all files as referenced in the manifest file have to exist. **I have copy-pasted the code in your question, and it works** (an alert shows up).

Comment: Incognito worked very well.  I appreciate the help.  Stupid mistake now that you've pointed it out.  Sigh.